# Ways to Prevent Automatic Shutdown by an IT Admin

Tags: windows, windows-7

My company pushes software updates to my computer about once every two days, and restarts the machine. This usually happens at night, so it is not disruptive, but if I am running long jobs overnight, the process kills my jobs.

Is there a way to prevent the system from shutting itself down when the machine is under heavy load? We run Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Why not call IT and explain it to them?

Comment: Do you know what system they use to push the updates?

Comment: Disconnect the network cable :-)

Answer (score 5):

If it is controlled by group policy, then no. You will need to contact them and explain why you need to keep your machine running overnight.